# How to return ViewModel from a supporting funtion other than action method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In the following example ([taken from MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components)) the author is returning a ViewModel from `GetItemsAsync(...)` function of type `Task<List<TodoItem>>`. What if I were to return a ViewModel, say, myViewModel from such a function (that is **NOT** an action method). How would I do that?

```
public class PriorityListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
        private readonly ToDoContext db;

        public PriorityListViewComponent(ToDoContext context)
        {
            db = context;
        }

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
        int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(maxPriority, isDone);
            return View(items);
        }
        private Task<List<TodoItem>> GetItemsAsync(int maxPriority, bool isDone)
        {
            return db.ToDo.Where(x => x.IsDone == isDone &&
                                 x.Priority <= maxPriority).ToListAsync();
        }       
}
```

**UPDATE**:

Following does not work. Please see the error below:

```
public class TestVCViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
        public async Task<CustomViewModel> GetCustomViewModel(int ProjID)
        {
            CustomViewModel myViewModel = await GetFromDb();
            return myViwModel;
        }

//then call it:

        public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(int ProjID)
        {

            return View(GetCustomViewModel(ProjID));
        }
}
```

**View**:

```
@model myWebApp.Models.CustomViewModel
...Some html here....
@await Component.InvokeAsync("TestVC", new { ProjID = Model.ProjectId });
--some other html here...
```

**Error**:

InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[myWebApp.Models.CustomViewModel]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'myWebApp.Models.CustomViewModel'.

**My Comments**:

But if you see this [MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) I'm doing almost the same except that I am using `Task<CustomViewModel>...` instead of `Task<List<TodoItem>>` that the article is using.

Comment: Are you asking how to return a value from a method?

Comment: @EdPlunkett No. I need to return myViewModel after populating it from Db. I can do populating part. I am confused about the signature of the function in such a case where the function is not an action method.

Comment: I apologize, I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 2):

In your UPDATE code you must await GetCustomViewModel call

Replace

```
  return View(GetCustomViewModel(ProjID));
```

with

```
  return View(await GetCustomViewModel(ProjID));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's how you would write an async method to return a custom type:

```
public async Task<CustomViewModel> GetCustomViewModel()
{
    CustomViewModel myViewModel = await GetFromDb();
    return myViwModel;
}
```

then call it:

```
var customViewModel = await GetCustomViewModel();
```

Comment: Your suggestion may be close. But I'm still getting an error. I've added an UPDATE section to my post above to explain what I'm doing.

Comment: I think you should add await (not sure where), I just watched pluralsight tutorial about it.